# How to put interleave, column, stripe, slab together in MS Storage Space

Tags: storage-spaces

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVcxP.png)

For more understanding my question, pls visit that image from above link.

Let's say we use two-way mirror  ---> create Virtual Disk ---> create a volume with 2GB size ---> now write 1GB data to it.

Storage Spaces starts by dividing the volume into many 'slabs', each 256 MB in size, so 1GB ,it's 4 slabs.

For each slab, two copies are made and placed on different drives in different servers (here is Server 1 and Server 2).

Storage Spaces describes a stripe via two parameters, NumberOfColumns (my case is 2 ) and Interleave ( Default is 256KB )

Storage Space start the first stripe (width of 512 KB), it write 256KB to disk 1(first column or Slab 1) , and do a copy to disk 3 ,then write 256KB to disk 4 (second conlumn or Slab 2 ), do a copy to disk 2 . then the second stripe , third stripe ...
After 1000 times' write , 1000 * 256KB * 2columns, then Slab 1 and Slab 2 is achieved or completed.

Then Storage Space create Slab 3 and Slab 4, after another 1000 times' write to Slab 3 and Slab 4 .then Slab 3 and 4 is also completed.

Afer Slab 1,2,3,4 is completed , Finally, 1 GB data' write operation is completed

**Question : Does Storage Space work  like this way ?**

Officail Web site explanation:
For Slab : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/deploy-standalone-storage-spaces